# How to retrieve a generic list from session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have a list that I put in session:

```
Session.Add("SessionList", mylist);
```

How to retrieve it back from the session?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var list = Session["SessionList"] as List<whatevertypeYouUsed>;

if (list != null){
   // blah...
}
```

I prefer to use the `as` keyword since there is no 100% guarantee that the Session will contain the list (due to application pool refresh, website being restarted, etc). Gives you that extra bit of defence to avoid a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
var myList = (List<WhateverTypeItIs>)Session["SessionList"];
```

Answer (score 1):

liek this...

```
 var list = Session["SessionList"] as List<whateveritis>;
```

or you can cast like this

```
 var List1 = (List<typespecified>)Session["SessionList"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below

```
 var list  = Session["SessionList"] as List<typespecified>;
```

OR also you can **cast** like below

```
var list = (List<typespecified>)Session["SessionList"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Var sessionlist = (List<Type of list>) Session["CustomerSessionList"];
```

Comment: Var sessionlist = (List<Customer>)Session["CustomerSessionList"];